# Display nearest shop to one user thanks to ampscript and latitude longitude

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, geolocation

I have 2 database with
- the geographical address of users (latitude and longitude)
- the geographical address of my shops (latitude and longitude)

I want to display in an email the 3 nearest shops from each user.

I thought of two solutions:
**- merge the 2 table to have a 3rd one looking like**
USER | SHOPS_NEARBY_1| SHOPS_NEARBY_2| SHOPS_NEARBY_3 
or
USER | SHOPS | DISTANCE_USER_SHOPS
**- use an ampscript formula directly in an email to show the shops with distance < x**

I am afraid I will have way too much lines in my first solution and I am not sure that the formulas allowed for ampscript will be able to calcul a distance 
What do you think would be the best solution? Is there another way?

Comment: are latitude and longitude in same field or separate fields?

Comment: separate fields

Comment: you could likely use the subtract function on these if you format them as decimals to get distance between locations - but you would need to work on a solution for comparing negative lat/long to positive lat/long.  Likely something with indexof and if statements.

Comment: Do you know the formulas I should use? I thought I would need cosinus and so on

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with subtraction/addition. I would not use this as a drop dead accurate approach, but for a simple comparison this should be accurate enough.

The easiest is if you have the '[Signed degrees](http://www.geomidpoint.com/latlon.html)' format (41.2500)  From here you have a range of -180 to 180 - but each is a decimal format value. It is a little trickier than just simple subtraction, but not as difficult as others may think.

> **Making the Calculation**
>
> Here’s where your math is put to test. If both
>   locations are on the same side of the equator, then you must deduct
>   the smaller figure from the larger. If they are on opposite sides of
>   the equator, then you must add the two figures together. Forget about
>   any minus signs that you may see -- they just signify that the figure
>   is the number of degrees to the south of the equator.

Example AMPScript:

```
%%[

    SET @Long = AttributeValue(yourLongitude)
    SET @StoreLong = AttributeValue(yourStoreLong)

    /* YOU MAY NEED TO CONVERT TO DECIMAL FORMAT IF STORED AS TEXT */

    IF @Long > @StoreLong THEN

       SET @First = @Long
       SET @Second = @StoreLong

    ELSE   

       SET @First = @StoreLong
       SET @Second = @Long

    ENDIF

    IF INDEXOF(@Long, "-") > 0 OR INDEXOF(@StoreLong, "-") > 0 THEN

       SET @longDistance = ADD(@First, @Second)

    ELSE

      SET @longDistance = SUBTRACT(@First, @Second)

    ENDIF

]%%
```

The tricky part comes in if your Lat/Long is in [any other format](http://www.geomidpoint.com/latlon.html) (something like: 41°25'01"N).  You would then need to convert this into 'Signed degrees' format to utilize the above. ([ref](https://www.cfa.harvard.edu/space_geodesy/ATLAS/cme_convert.html))

> **To convert the Latitude or Longitude to Map Coordinates (MC):**
>
> Step 1: Multiply (×) the "degrees" by 60
>
> Step 2: Add (+) the "minutes"
>
> Step 3: If the Latitude (Longitude) degrees are S (W) use a minus sign ("-") in front. This result is the Latitude (Longitude) converted to Minutes.
>
> **Latitude Map Coordinates:**
>
> Step 1: Degrees × 60 = 42 × 60 = 2520
>
> Step 2: 2520 + 20.736 = 2540.736
>
> Step 3: The Latitude is not "S" so the Latitude converted to Minutes
>   is 2540.736
>
> **Longitude Map Coordinates:**
>
> Step 1: Degrees × 60 = 71 × 60 = 4260
>
> Step 2: 4260 + 5.745 = 4265.745
>
> Step 3: The Longitude is "W" so the answer is -4265.745

Comment: So, if I use longitude only would it be sufficient to have an idea of the closest store? Or should I add the longitude distance and the latitude one?

Comment: I would definitely use both numbers - perhaps even make it an average.  As someone could be in New Jersey(USA) and another in Turkey and they would have very similar latitude, but hugely different longitude.